# Create mssql job via Liquibase

Tags: sql-server, liquibase, jobs

I would like to create job on sql server via liquibase. I have raw sql file, which remove job if exists and define a new one.

I have to start script from `'use msdb'` clause in order to have an access to `sp_add_job/sp_delete` job procedures.

The job is created correctly, but after executing liquibase returns error. It doesn't see databasechangelog table.

I guess the clause of this problem is that after script liquibase is in `msdb`, but it should be in my db.

I don't want to use name of my db in script, because it may be different in another enviroment. What is the correct way to create mssql job via `liquibase`?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Could you provide the actual changeSet you're executing?

Comment: SQL Agent jobs don't live inside a user database, ever. They are kept in `msdb`. If your job has to execute code against a user database (or stored procedures inside a user database) or the job creation script has to create objects within your user database, you'll need to parameterize your creation script so that the user database name can be passed in when it's executed.

Comment: @alroc - I think the OP gets that. The issue isn't RUNNing the SQL Job... it's CREATING the SQL Job in the first place ala Liquibase.  When the liquibase script is then done, it's trying to update the changelog, which it can't because the changelog is back in the user's database, but at that moment, the context is msdb.  It's almost a chicken/egg kind of situation. Personaly, I don't like deploying SQL Job blindly like this, I've seen too much go wrong. It would be nicer/easier to supply the script and some steps for someone to follow to get it done.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach would be to use changelog parameters to specify the name of the database that is being managed. You might have something like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="user-database" value="dev-user" context="DEV"/>
    <property name="user-database" value="test-user" context="TEST"/>
    <property name="user-database" value="prod-user" context="PROD"/>

    <changeSet id="1" author="joe">
         <sql endDelimiter="\nGO" splitStatements="true">
           use MSDB
           GO

           (create the job you need)
           GO

           use ${user-database}
           GO
         </sql>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The `${user-database}` will be replaced with the value of the user-database property depending on the context you have set. You would then run the `liquibase update` command with `--contexts=DEV` or `--contexts=TEST`, etc.

ChangeLog parameters are documented at https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html